# Datagrid shows only one record

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

everything looks fine from my point of view, but the dataGrid shows only the first item which has been added to the grid.

The XAML part:

```
   <DataGrid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="dataGridIE"
              VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HeadersVisibility="All" CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserResizeColumns="False"
              AutoGenerateColumns="True" ColumnWidth="100" CanUserAddRows="True" CanUserDeleteRows="True" 
              Height="97" Margin="23,38,16,38" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Width="682">
                     <!--<DataGrid.Columns>
                       <DataGridTextColumn Header="Key" Binding="{Binding Key}" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Value" Binding="{Binding Value.xPath}" />
                    </DataGrid.Columns>-->
                </DataGrid>
```

Declarative part for the list(code behind):

```
private List<IEGridViewEntry> _fillEntryDictionary;
```

The struct, that needs to be bound:

```
        public struct IEGridViewEntry //: INotifyPropertyChanged
        {

            private ...

            public string wordPlaceHolder
            {
                get { return _wordPlaceHolder; }
                set { _wordPlaceHolder = value; }
            }

            ...
};
```

The way I fill it:

```
_fillEntryDictionary.Add(new IEGridViewEntry(refHtmlElement));
dataGridIE.ItemsSource = _fillEntryDictionary;
```

When Debugging everything looks good and filled..

```
_fillEntryDictionary = Count = 2
[0] = {name1.name.IEGridViewEntry}
```

Copied expression(Debugging):

```
(new System.Collections.Generic.Mscorlib_CollectionDebugView<name1.name.IEGridViewEntry>(_fillEntryDictionary)).Items[0]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you using struct for the entity, which must be a class?

Comment: structs are value types and thereby faster, but i used to use a class and the same problem remained( by the way also include the interface INotifyPropertyChanged)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set ItemsSource="{Binding}" for datagrid, and populate it with setting .DataContext = ObservableColelction, instead of setting a List